# extracting strings after traversing errors in Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

As in Ecto, we have changeset and in the case of invalid changeset, we can traverse errors according to [Traverse error](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#traverse_errors/2). But this gave us a very complicated JSON such as

```
  {
    "to_date": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "title": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "requested_by": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "from_date": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "exid": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
```

can't we do something wth that in Elixir so we can get the straight strings such as "Exid can't be blank" or such as an object

```
{
  to_date: "to_date can't be bank"
}
```

Update:
This is the result after traversing errors

```
%{exid: ["can't be blank"], from_date: ["can't be blank"],
  requested_by: ["can't be blank"], title: ["can't be blank"],
  to_date: ["can't be blank"]}
```

is there any way to get "exid cant be blank" by using `Enum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert it to a list of strigs, you can do something like:

```
for {key, values} <- errors, value <- values, do: "#{key} #{value}"
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> errors = %{exid: ["can't be blank", "can't be something else"], from_date: ["can't be blank"],
...(1)>   requested_by: ["can't be blank"], title: ["can't be blank"],
...(1)>   to_date: ["can't be blank"]}
%{exid: ["can't be blank", "can't be something else"],
  from_date: ["can't be blank"], requested_by: ["can't be blank"],
  title: ["can't be blank"], to_date: ["can't be blank"]}
iex(2)> for {key, values} <- errors, value <- values, do: "#{key} #{value}"
["exid can't be blank", "exid can't be something else",
 "from_date can't be blank", "requested_by can't be blank",
 "title can't be blank", "to_date can't be blank"]
```

Comment: why you removed enum?